# In academic Japanese, should old places be written with 新字体 or 旧字体?

Tags: academic-japanese

## Japanese

以下の大学名をご覧ください：

> 東北帝国大学

旧帝大は旧帝大としてはもう無くなっているので、学術論文に旧字体の方（東北帝國大學）か新字体の方（東北帝国大学）のどちらを使うのが正しいですか。

また、施設が現在も存在しているかどうかが、前の名称だった頃の名称の新・旧字体の使い方に対して関係があるかどうか教えてください。

## English

Consider for instance

> 東北帝国大学

Since the 旧帝大 are no longer 旧帝大, when writing in an academic paper, should one write 東北帝国大学 or 東北帝國大學?

Also, does it matter whether an institution continues to this day for whether it should be written in 旧字体 or 新字体 for something historical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this greatly depends on the type of your article and the manuscript guideline of the journal. When in doubt, you have to contact an editor and ask about it.

In general, unless your article is directly about the Japanese literature/language/history itself, you can use 新字体. For example, if your article is about vitamins and you just want to quickly mention where and when they were discovered, you can simply use 帝国大学. But it's safe to preserve the original usage of kanji in quotes.

Comment: To this I would just add that there are cases where the institution itself still uses 旧字体, in which case following their example is usually more common than not. For example, Keio University still writes its name 慶應, and most people writing about it follow suit, although 慶応 is not unheard of. (Not to mention an even simpler orthography apparently used by the Keio community which consists of just the letters "K" and "O" under 广 radicals.)

Answer (score 0):

C'mon, 旧字体 is called as such because people no longer use them in daily life... If you're really deeply into the history of Japan, it *might* make *some* sense to use them.

Comment: 二つのコメントを置きます。まず、「C'mon」はちょっと失礼な感じがする言葉で（この場面で「ふざけるな」らしい）、使わない方がいいと思います。また、「daily life」と「学術論文」は同じものではなくと思います。

Comment: @virmaior Ur talkin bout sth lk "shud I stick to BE when I write a paper on British history?"